# Access to the value of a small child object

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm looking for a way to access the value of the name attribute of the sub-category. I get undefined when I access via.
I can access the values of the attributes of the sub objects but not the values of the attributes of the sub=>sub objects.

```
this.data.subCategory.category.name 



This is the model

export interface Article{
    id:number;
    color:string;
    createAt:string;
    endAt:string;
    gender:Gender;
    image:string;
    make: Make;
    name:string;
    price:number;
    quantity:number;
    shopcart:null;
    stock: Stock;
    subCategory:SubCategory;
}

export interface Category{
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

export interface SubCategory{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    category: Category; 
}
```

Comment: `articles` is an array, which you convert to a string, then convert back to an array, and then try to access an item in the array like an object? I think you should read the [docs on working with arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) in javascript

Comment: My problem is how can access to small child(name of category) in this object with model Article

Comment: before accessing, check whether the this.data is initialised.

Comment: It is a datas:BehaviorSubject<Article[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Article[]>([])

Comment: If i use this.data.subCategory.name is get name of subCategory but this.data.subCategory.name.category.name give me undefined.